# sendKeys and click() is not working. Unable to get elements and I am using protractor javascript code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, automated-tests

```
<input class="form-control validation-field ng-dirty ng-touched ng-invalid" placeholder="Password" type="password">
```

Am using this to get the element but its not sending keys and also not showing any error message. I have tried on both Firefox and google chrome.

```
element.all(By.css('.form-control.validation-field.ng-dirty.ng-valid.ng-touched')).sendKeys('sample code');
```

This is my conf.js file

// An example configuration file.

```
exports.config = {
    directConnect: true,

    // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'firefox'
    },

    // Framework to use. Jasmine is recommended.
    framework: 'jasmine',

    // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directory when
    // protractor is called.
    specs: ['example_spec.js'],

    // Options to be passed to Jasmine.
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 100000
    }
};
```

If I use `get(0)` or `get(1)` its showing error that cannot locate using this css . Why?

Comment: Try `element.all(By.css('input[type="password"]')).sendKeys('sample code');`. Share  the DOM element to give a clear picture on the problem.

Comment: "<input class="form-control validation-field ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched" placeholder="Email" type="text">"

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your css is not correct, instead of .ng-valid you should place .ng-invalid

```
element.all(By.css('.form-control.validation-field.ng-dirty.ng-invalid.ng-touched')).sendKeys('sample code');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using class name is not encouraged because they may change in near future.

Suppose you are trying to input user name the preceding node will contain visible text (i.e) user name or something

Try to find that node and then following input element.

example:

```
//*[contains(text(),"User Name")]/following-sibling::input
```

Comment: but am having an error "Failed: unknown error: cannot focus element"

Comment: Could you open browser developer window and check if xpath is correct and highlighting the correct node

Comment: <input class="form-control validation-field ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched" placeholder="Email" type="text">

Comment: Try using browser execute command.

May be the elements in the page are over lapped

Comment: please can you tell me in detail as am new ..dont much about protractor and javascript

Comment: <input class="form-control validation-field ng-dirty ng-valid ng-touched" placeholder="Email" type="text">...i want to use this class and kindly guide how can i get the element using this class

Answer (score 0):

Before trying my suggestions please check the answer from `Sanja Paskova`.

I can see a few potential problems here:

1) You are using `By.css()` with an uppercase `B` instead of `by.css()` with lowercase `b`. I don't know if it's the same.

2) `element.all()` returns an `ElementArrayFinder` and not an `ElementFinder`. You should either use `element.all(by.css('foo')).first().sendKeys('bla');` OR `element(by.css('foo')).sendKeys('bla');`.

3) If it's not point 1 and 2 try to click the input  before sending keys:

```
  var input = element(by.css('.form-control.validation-field.ng-dirty.ng-valid.ng-touched'));
  input.click().then(function() {
      input.sendKeys('sample code');
    });
```

Just some guesses.

Comment: i have tried every solution. but it shows an error "Failed: unknown error: cannot focus element"

Comment: "form-group text-left" am using this to get element...var username=element.all(By.css('.form-group.text-left')).first();
username.click(); and it works perfect...click on the text box...but when  I try to sendKeys using "username.sendKeys('saqib@test.com');" it does not work using an error " Failed: unknown error: cannot focus element
      (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.99)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)"

Comment: <input class="form-control validation-field ng-dirty ng-valid ng-touched" placeholder="Email" type="text">...i want to use this class and kindly guide how can i get the element using this class

Comment: '//input[contains(@class,"form-control validation-field ng-dirty ng-valid ng-touched")]'